# Pascal Некорекктное отображение символов в файле

Tags: pascal

Есть задачка на работу с файлом. Создаю файл типа integer. Записываю туда 10 чисел, но при открытии через блокнот - там другие символы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что добавить для корректного отображения.
Вот просто запись в файл:

```
const 
n=10; 

var 
a:array[1..n] of integer; 
f:file of integer; 
i,min,o,sum:integer; 

begin 
  randomize; 
  assign(f, 'file1.txt'); 
  rewrite(f); 
  for i:=1 to n do 
  begin 
    a[i]:=random(20); 
    write(f, a[i]); 
  end; 
  close(f); 
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы пишите в файл числа типа `integer`, то есть по сути это бинарный файл. Текстовый файл состоит из символов. При открытии файла через блокнот он отображает коды символов введенных Вами чисел, причем символы с ASCII кодом менее 32 нечитабельные. Чтобы введенные числа отображались нужно

1. Поменять формат файла на Text

   f:Text;
2. преобразовать число в строку функцией Str

Для этого добавим переменную `S: string` в раздел `Var`

а перед выводом делаем преобразование

Вместо `write(f ,a[i]);`:

```
Str(a[i], S);
Write(f, S + ' ');
```

Для читабельности добавляем пробел. Тогда файл будет читаемым, но если Вы ведете дальнейшую обработку, то лучше оставить файл в формате `integer`, так как при обработке файла удобнее использовать бинарный формат. Вы сразу зачитываете числа в родном формате без преобразования.

Всё зависит от поставленных задач.

Для преобразования строки в число используют функцию `Val`.

Функция `chr` не сработает в данном случае, потому что формат файла не `file of char`.

Comment: Процедура `write` сама прекрасно умеет печатать целые числа, поэтому нет необходимости звать `str`. Другими словами, достаточно вызывать `write(f, a[i]);`, но только файл должен быть текстовым, как сказано выше, а не `file of integer`.